# Calling duplex wcf service method from uwp have no effect

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp, duplex

I am developing an UWP application which consumes wcf duplex service made by myself. The problem occurs when I try to call a method from service, literally method does not firing up and no breakpoint in service code is hitted.

This is my configuration in host application

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService.Services.ImageExchangeService" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4322/WcfService/Services/ImageExchangeService/tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfService.Services.IImageExchangeService" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"></endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4323/WcfService/Services/ImageExchangeService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4321/WcfService/Services/ImageExchangeService" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>  
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
        set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
        set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
        to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpBinding">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is my service interface

```
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IImageExchangeClient), SessionMode =SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IImageExchangeService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Connect(string deviceIdentifier); 
    }
```

This is my implementation of above interface

```
  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults =true)]
    public class ImageExchangeService : IImageExchangeService
    {
        private Dictionary<string, IImageExchangeClient> _connectedDevices = new Dictionary<string, IImageExchangeClient>();


        public void Connect(string deviceIdentifier)
        {
           var connection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IImageExchangeClient>();
            if (!_connectedDevices.ContainsKey(deviceIdentifier))
            {
                _connectedDevices.Add(deviceIdentifier, connection);
            }
            else
            {
                _connectedDevices[deviceIdentifier] = connection;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nDevice connected: {0}", deviceIdentifier);


        }
}
```

and finally this is my UWP code where I trying to call `Connect` method

```
        public async void InitializeImageExchangeClient()
        {

            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4322/WcfService/Services/ImageExchangeService/tcp"));
            var InstanceContext = new InstanceContext(new ImageExchangeCallback());

            var client = new ImageExchangeService.ImageExchangeServiceClient(buildBinding(), endpoint);
            var channelFactory = (DuplexChannelFactory<IImageExchangeService>)(client.ChannelFactory);
            var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel(InstanceContext);
            await proxy.ConnectAsync(DeviceIdentifier);
}
```

I have also tried other approach of cal this method like:

```
            var client = new ImageExchangeServiceClientBase(InstanceContext, buildBinding(), endpoint);
            await client.OpenAsync();
            await client.ConnectAsync(DeviceIdentifier);
```

`buildBinding()` function looks like this:

```
private NetTcpBinding buildBinding()
        {
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding()
            {

                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
                },
                OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,


            };
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

            return binding;
        }
```

Actual result is the method `Connect` is not firing up, and when I toggle breakpoint on this method it is not hitted. 
Other non-duplex services are working fine without a problem.
When I implemented this service in WPF application the method is calling properly and everything works fine, the problem is when I trying to implement this in UWP  architecture. 
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Have you add **Private Networks** capability in your UWP manifest file?

Comment: Yes, Private Networks and Internet capabilities are checked.

Comment: What about `EnterpriseAuthentication` `Shared User Certificates` capability?

Comment: These are checked too.

Comment: Could you use fiddler to check if the request has been send successfully？

Comment: Unfortunately fiddler giving no result when I calling up duplex service method. Normal non-duplex service method calls are visible in fiddler logs.

Comment: Have allowed your throw the firewall in window security setting?

Comment: Yes, this app is allowed in windows firewall.